# Using iOS 8 features on iOS 7 phones, hidesBarsOnSwipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I would like to use UINavigationControllers new hidesBarsOnSwipe to replace a self made hack doing the same thing. I guess this is more of a general question, but if I develop using the iOS 8 SDKs and deploy to a phone running iOS 7, what will happen?

```
UINavigationController *nc = [UINavigationController new];
nc.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES; // Hides the navigation bars when scrolling.
```

Will this have the desired effect on iOS 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will crash on iOS 7 because `UINavigationController` doesn't respond to `setHidesBarOnSwipe:` selector (the method is implemented only on iOS 8 or newer). You can add a safety check:

```
if([nc respondsToSelector:@selector(setHidesBarOnSwipe:)]) {
  ns.hidesBarOnSwipe = YES;
}
else {
// use your old hack if you want to
}
```